# Function String Caml light

Tags: string, ocaml, caml, light

I need a function that take a string and a char , it slides the string and if it found the char return TRUE else FALSE.

This is my start point:

```
let rec check s a = match s with
    "" -> false
    | x::xs -> if x = a then true else check xs a ;;
```

I can’t use the library function of caml light (like index_char)

Thanks for help!

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: You code will work perfectly for a list of chars. But a string isn't a list of chars in OCaml (though sometimes it would be nice if it was).

Answer (score 0):

I will leave the explanation of how it works to you, this is my solution:

```
strobel@suse131:~> rlwrap camllight 
>       Caml Light version 0.75    
let findchar c s =
 let len = string_length s in
 let rec f1 i s = 
   if i = len then false 
   else if s.[i]=c then true else f1 (succ i) s in
     f1 0 s
;;
findchar : char -> string -> bool = <fun>
#let s = "this is the searched string";;
s : string = "this is the searched string"
#findchar `a` s;;
- : bool = true
#findchar `y` s;;
- : bool = false
```

Additional exercises:

- could we leave out parameter s in the f1 definition?
- how do we call the usage / occurence of `len` in the body of f1?